# Rotas dinâmicas para páginas do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quero criar um sistema de rotas dinâmico, sem precisar codificar gambiarras.

Vamos lá.

Tenho as Rotas:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web'],
    'namespace' => 'LaraShop\Front\Http\Controllers',
    'as' => 'page'
], function()
{
    /*
     * Páginas padrão
     */
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('.home');
    Route::get('/contato', 'PagesController@show')->name('.contact');

    /*
     * Rotas Dinâmicas
     */
    Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@getPage');

});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
    'namespace' => 'LaraShop\Admin\Http\Controllers',
    'as' => 'admin'
], function() {
    // rotas do admin
});
```

A questão é, qual a melhor maneira do `{page}` passar pela rota /admin sem causar erro?

Comment: Não está correto essa rota porque ela vai chocar com `/`, com `/contato` etc ... não pode ter na raiz algo dinâmico se existe outras rotas que tem a mesma nomenclatura.

Answer (score 1):

Posicione sua rota no final do arquivo.

```
Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@getPage');
```

No `PageController@getPage`, verifique qual página é e se ela possui uma `view` por exemplo e caso não encontre de um `abort(404)`